# htaccess query string /?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've been searching similar examples but I was not able to find the answer in WordPress.

In google analytics I can see various string types for the same url's coming in. I looked at the htaccess file and deactivated the cache system but it's still occurring. Not sure why yet.

Now in htaccess I would like to redirect all those url's to the correct one:

Example:
// CORRECT:  ...domain.com/everest-nepal/

// INCORRECT 1: ...domain.com/everest-nepal/?/

// INCORRECT 2: ...domain.com/everest-nepal/?/=

// CORRECT 3: ...domain.com/everest-nepal/?amp (this is amp related and not interested in redirecting it to the canonical url)

Is there a possible rewrite condition that could be applied in htaccess to redirect all these url's coming with this strange /?* at the end avoiding the amp?

Thanks and regards
Enric

Answer (score 0):

Once you update permalinks in wordpress admin you will get .htaccess code below like this, You need to create .htaccess file in your root folder, and paste this below code, this should work,

[image]

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks Prabu. I already have the same settings and lines in .htaccess

Comment: The lines have always been there. According to google analytics those examples (domain.com/everest-nepal/?/) are still coming in...